# No connection strings named <EntityName> could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

I am using Entity Framework Database First. When I am building my project I am getting this error:

> No connection strings named 'RegistrationEntities' could be found in the application config file

But when I checked my app.config file there is a connection string.
[Screenshot of the connection string in my app.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PdZs.png)

When I am running the project it runs smoothly but I just want to remove that error.

The error is being triggered whenever I load a data from the database using the Entity Framework.

ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ParentModel> ParentCollection { get; set; }

    public List<Parent> ParentList { get; set; }

    public ParentModel ParentModel { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Load();
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        using (RegistrationEntities registrationContext = new RegistrationEntities())
        {
            ParentList = registrationContext.Parents.ToList();


            for (int i = 0; i < ParentList.Count; i++)
            {
                ParentModel = new ParentModel()
                {
                    PId = ParentList[i].P_Id,
                    PLastName = ParentList[i].P_LastName,
                    PFirstName = ParentList[i].P_FirstName,
                    PMiddleName = ParentList[i].P_MiddleName,
                    PAddress = ParentList[i].P_Address,
                    PContactNo = ParentList[i].P_ContactNo,
                    PEmail = ParentList[i].P_Email,
                    PUsername = ParentList[i].P_Username,
                    PPassword = ParentList[i].P_Password,
                    PCreatedOn = ParentList[i].P_CreatedOn,
                    PUpdatedAt = ParentList[i].P_UpdatedAt
                };

                ParentCollection.Add(ParentModel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you any other config file other than the one in EF/DataAccess Layer ? May be like web.Config?I think the application looks for connection string in web.Config.

Comment: I have a packeges.config file. By the way I am using WPF.

Comment: Where is this app.config situated? You should locate this connectionstrings section in the app.config (web.config for web projects) of your executing program (in your case the WPF project).

Comment: @hbulens yes the app.config is situated inside my WPF project.